# Uploaded directory should not have any "execute" permission

Tags: php, security

I'm kind of new in PHP. How can I check on a upload file in PHP if the file is executable? I found this function [is_executable](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.is-executable.php) but I'm not sure if this function checks only the name of the file... What if I change the name of upload.exe in upload.txt? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix-like systems (macOS, all Linux flavours and some others), `is_executable()` returns `TRUE` if the file has the "execute" bit set (`x` on `ls -l`). The name of the file plays no role for the system when it needs to decide if a file is executable or not.

A fresh uploaded file never has this bit set; the file is generated by the PHP interpreter and it has no reason to set it.

---

On Windows, `is_executable()` asks the OS if the file is executable. The OS looks into the file header to see if it looks like a [`PE` executable format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). This includes the `.exe` and `.dll` files and some other file types. It is not possible to fool `is_executable()` on Windows by renaming a real executable to `upload.txt`.

But, on Windows, all file formats that one can open by double-clicking them in Explorer can be "executed". The `.html` files, f.e. open in the default browser. They can be "launched" using any of the [PHP functions that execute a program](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php), even if `is_executable()` returns `FALSE` for them.

Comment: aha, thanks, but as a primary security check it is enough to use is_executable($_FILES['importFile']['name'])?

Comment: `$_FILES['importFile']['name']` is [the original name of the file on the client machine](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). It doesn't matter and it can be fake. In the PHP script you are dealing with `$_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name']`. If your web server **is not** a Windows machine then `is_executable($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name'])` always returns `FALSE` and it doesn't help you with anything.

Comment: both is_executable($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name']) and is_executable($_FILES['importFile']['name']) returns me... nothing. I'm on windows(7).

Comment: `$_FILES['importFile']['name']` is just a name, it doesn't denote a file that exists on the server. Read more about [uploads handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: ok, and then, why echo 'exec='.is_executable($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name']); returns exec= (emply)?...

Comment: echo 'exec='.is_executable($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name']);
echo 'filesize='.filesize($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name']);
returns exec=filesize=512512...

Comment: This is how a `FALSE` looks like when it is [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)-ed.

Comment: ok, but this means that is_executable($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name']); for a renamed executable (into a .txt) looks only to file ext...

Comment: The bottom line is: as long as you don't intend to execute the file it doesn't matter what `is_executable()` returns or if the file is really executable or not. I recommend you to concentrate on how you handle the file and less on what the file contains. The border between an executable and a data file is very thin these days.

Comment: my code is dealing with a file the user is uploading. If the file is txt it reads the content and tries to execute some sql from within the txt. If it is an executable renamed into a txt it opens the file and looses some time trying to execute some mumbo-jumbo from the exe - it gives the errors but it would be nice to know that it is an "masked" executable...

Comment: *"tries to execute some sql from within the txt"* -- executing content uploaded by the user [is never a good idea](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: that was corrected in the last version but I have to make some changes into some older version and I'm trying to treat some issues...